# Set background image to hostView CorePlot pieChart

Tags: ios, core-plot

I want to add backgroung image to the hostView (image under my diagram). I doing this:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.fill=[(CPTFill *)[CPTFill alloc] initWithImage:[CPTImage imageForPNGFile:@"test.png"]];
```

And this:

```
graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageWithCGImage:myCGImage]];
```

And this:

```
 CALayer *caL = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    caL.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"100.png"].CGImage;

    [self.hostView.layer addSublayer:caL];
```

But all this doesn't work. I tried it in `configureHost` and `configureGraph` methods. 
What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Tried to init CPTImage by path:

```
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"100" ofType:@"png"];

    if (filePath) {
        NSLog(@"file exs");
        graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageForPNGFile:filePath]];
    }
```

I can see that file exist, but this doesn't work too

Comment: Did you set the background color of the `hostView` to `clearColor` before?

Comment: If you want to fill the whole graph with your image, the second one (`graph.fill = …`) will work. Have you verified that `myCGImage` was initialized correctly?

Comment: I used fill method like this graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageForPNGFile:@"100.png"]]; But it doesn't work